# What is the proper problem name / algorithm for this problem description in computer science theory?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

The problem is that I have X items of varying weighted values that must go into Y containers. The containers are of differing sizes (e.g. hold differing maximum weights). The total load of each container must be approximately equivalent to the others, but the containers don't need to be full or minimized. All of the containers must be used.

This reminds me of the "knapsack" problem, but I have multiple knapsacks of differing sizes and the loads between them all must be relatively equivalent (e.g. one knapsack may only hold 12 pounds, and another knapsack may only hold 8 pounds, but they both need to be filled with the same percentage of total weight they can carry). It also reminds me of the "bin packing" problem, but that doesn't deal with the varying bin sizes or that the bins don't need to be full or minimized, they just need equivalent loads and all of them need to be used.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction as to the name of this problem within data structures and algorithm theory? I'd also be interested in any algorithms or heuristics that may be commonly used to solve a problem like this or info about the possible time complexity.

Comment: knapsack problem or packing problem

Comment: It's definitely in the class of optimization problems, but it's a generalization of the knapsack problem (in which case it may have a better name), not the knapsack problem itself, and the packing problem typically attempts to optimize for a minimum with a uniform set of objects, this is minimizing the standard deviation with a heterogeneous set of objects.

Comment: Please note: this isn't a "homework" problem or any such thing. Its an actual "real world" problem that I need to code a solution for, but I'm having difficulty designing an effective algorithm on my own or finding a similar problem description.

Comment: Hmm I write this as a comment rather than an answer because I feel it is not very satisfactory, but a possible heuristic is to line up the containers from biggest to smallest, and likewise the items from biggest to smallest, and place X_1 into Y_1 and X_2 into Y_2, and when you reach the end, wrap around to put X_(n+1) into Y_1, etc. Of course the complexity of this is basically just the same as the two sorts. Possibly could be used in conjunction with some sort of guess-and-improve or hill climbing algorithm (I have very limited experience with these).

Comment: actually it sounds more like subset sum or partition (because given that _all_ the objects must go into the containers, and given that the proportions should be equivalent, we can actually find out the "ideal" weight per container).

Comment: Mitches: @Shwartz, I thought of something similar, but my "wrapping" heuristics didn't produce a satisfactory solution. I need to consider possibilities like the 2 median items need to be combined with an arbitrary item from the set. @Wheat or whoever gave him the +1, could one of you please explain how this is actually the knapsack or packing problem? I've read about those a bit and still can't wrap my head around an effective implementation.

Comment: Can you quantify "approximately equivalent"?  eg you could use the variance of the weights or alternatively the maximum difference in weights.  Once this has been clarified, you might be able to frame the problem as a linear programming or quadratic programming problem.

Comment: i would think it's integer programming rather than linear or quadratic programming (in that the integrality of the problem is the defining characteristic).

Comment: Please be explicit about exactly what you're trying to optimise.  It *seems* like you want the proportion of capacity used for each container to be the same (e.g. 80% of each container's capacity gets used), but I would be surprised if that's actually a hard constraint (i.e. I'm guessing that a solution with one container having 79% used is fine).  If you just want them to be "approximately the same", then your problem will not correspond to any "named" problem from CS.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You're understanding the problem description correctly. Are you saying there _is_ a named, corresponding problem in CS if I solve for equal proportions of capacity used by each container? (e.g. every container has exactly 80% used)

Comment: @noneme: Not to my knowledge I'm afraid, although it's at least possible that one exists.  OTOH many (most) problem instances will have no solution -- correct?  Which (a) is obviously a problem in its own right and (b) reduces the chances that this class of problems has been studied heavily.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Ok, thanks for the comments. It's at least good to know that I'm not banging my head against a problem that has an easy or widely known solution.

Comment: i don't think this problem has an easy solution, since partition is an instance of it (Y = 2, equal sized containers) - both the decision problem (i.e. strictly equal proportions) as well as the optimization problem (minimizing the difference in partition sizes). the 3-partition problem is also an instance of it, and that one is strongly NP-complete.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like multiple-knapsack to me. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems):

> If we have n items and m knapsacks with capacities Wi, we get the multiple knapsack problem

EDIT: Sorry, missed the bit about each container needing to be similarly loaded. Still, it *smells* like multiple-knapsack, albeit with an extra constraint.

Comment: And minus one, though. I agree that it _smells_ like multiple-knapsack, but knapsack has two-dimensional objects with associated costs (or size) and values, where you optimize for max(value), min(cost); this is optimizing for maximal standard deviation over the set of knapsacks, with only one-dimensional objects (associated size).

Answer (score 1):

If you map X to pictures of varying heights; and map Y to columns, then the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626520/fitting-n-varible-height-images-into-3-similar-length-column-layout/5689594#5689594) should work for you too. It is a worst-fit bin packing solution with pre-sorting and additional item swapping coded in Python with examples.