# Partition a list into subsets

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, yield-return

I have a list of items which I would like to partition into subsets. For the sake of discussion lets say they're files. I would like each subset to contain at most 5 files, and for the total size of the files in the subset to be less than 1 MB if possible. If a single file exceeds 1MB it should be in a subset by itself.

I wrote this up in a slightly more generic form, using a generic "item metric" instead of file size. But I suspect there's a simpler and/or better way to do this. Any suggestions?

Here's what I've got:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> InSetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int maxItemsPerSet, int maxMetricPerSet, Func<T, int> getMetric)
{
    int currentMetricSum = 0;
    List<T> currentSet = new List<T>();

    foreach (T listItem in source)
    {
        int itemMetric = getMetric(listItem);

        if (currentSet.Count > 0 && 
            (currentSet.Count >= maxItemsPerSet || (currentMetricSum + itemMetric) > maxMetricPerSet))
        {
            yield return currentSet;

            //Start a new subset
            currentSet = new List<T>();
            currentMetricSum = 0;
        }

        currentSet.Add(listItem);
        currentMetricSum += itemMetric;
    }

    //Return the last set
    yield return currentSet;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) and [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) LINQ extension methods.

Comment: If you're looking for optimal, this is a classic [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).  It looks like you've implemented first-fit (without a pre-sort). The question is are you looking for just cleaner code or a better solution?  If the former you might have better luck over at [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Oded - Take and Skip would not check the extra metric (file size in my example).

Comment: @RonWarholic - I figured there had to be a name for this problem, thanks! I'm mostly interested in cleaner code. In my actual use case it optimal distribution isn't very important.

Comment: @breischl - Fair point. But [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx) and [`SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile.aspx) will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bin packing is a NP-hard problem. The only way to get an *optimal* solution is to test all combinations. If there is a fixed number of distinct sizes, it can be systematically done using dynamic programming (there is an [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724521/69809) with sample code for this case), but the running time for such algorithm is terrible.

This means you should be looking for a heuristic which would get you close to the optimal solution in reasonable time. Your algorithm (first-fit) is a good starting point. With little effort, it can be slightly improved by presorting the items by decreasing size. There are, however, several other more-or-less complex heuristics which improve both speed and the results.

A [Google search](http://www.google.com/?q=bin%20packing%20heuristics) returned this as one of the results: [Basic analysis of bin-packing heuristics](http://bastian.rieck.ru/uni/bin_packing/) (there is a [paper](http://bastian.rieck.ru/uni/bin_packing/bin_packing.pdf) which analyses results). Apparently, a *best fit algorithm with a bin lookup table* provides good results with a reasonable running time.

Answer (score 0):

The 1MB test is missing, but otherwise your code looks OK to me. I do not think there is a significantly better way of doing it.

Comment: That was for the sake of argument. To do that you'd call the code I posted with maxMetricPerSet=1MB, and the getMetric function as something that returns file size.

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was a different limit for a single file than for several. Then your code is fine. Just go with it!