# How to implement a gapless block layout algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to display images in a grid layout that is 4 units wide by an arbitrary number of units high.

Each image in the grid may be 1x1, 1x2, 2x1 or 2x2 units. I'm also using jQuery masonry to try and eliminate some gaps in the layout.

The size an image is displayed at (1x1, 2x2, etc.) is a "preferred" size based on its dimensions.

I'm thinking that the easiest way to eliminate gaps in the layout would be to display certain images in the layout at sizes other than their preferred size. How can I do this algorithmically, maintaining the largest number of photos that are displayed at their preferred size, while overriding for those that are determined to be necessary for a gapless layout.

A visual example; I want to turn this:

[image]

into something like what they have on this website: http://500px.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626520/fitting-n-varible-height-images-into-3-similar-length-column-layout

Answer (score 0):

Just a start: I think this is an instance of [**bin packing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) which is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Np_complete) in the general case (see [this pdf](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/alkox/lehre/lvws1011/coalg/bin_packing.pdf)). Might be helpful to start searching for things in those terms... this is not a complete answer by any means.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is group pairs of 1x2s together, pairs of 2x1s together, and quadruples of 1x1s together.  Laying out lots of 2x2s is then easy, and only the odd-images out will need to be resized.  This (or something like it) is almost certainly what 500px.com does.

I suspect this solution doesn't really jive with your "laid out left-to-right, top-to-bottom" restriction.  But I'm not sure what that restriction means, exactly.  Perhaps if you could make it clear what that means we could help you better.

Comment: By left to right, top to bottom I just meant normal text flow. I guess it's not really necessary to state that.