# Evenly distribute int values into two lists whose sums must be nearly equal

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I want to evenly distribute int values of a list into two lists whose sums must be nearly equal. If they are not exactly equal, the difference should be returned.

```
li=[5,8,13,27,14]
first_list=[27,8)
second_list=[14,13,5]
return sum(first_list)-sum(second_list) #3
```

Comment: What have you tried? You're much more likely to get help here if you've already done some work and have a specific issue that you need assistance with.

Comment: You haven't provided any code showing any effort to make it happen, and haven't asked a question. Were you looking for permission? If so, please - go ahead and distribute the ints however you see fit.

Comment: Make a histogram, split in the middle? Alternatively sample at random untill you strike a treshold for the difference. I really see no simple solution that won't require infinite loops.

Comment: [The following answer][1] with source code can be applied to that problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626520/fitting-n-varible-height-images-into-3-similar-length-column-layout/5689594#5689594

Answer (score 4):

This is the optimization problem for [**Partition Problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

There is no known polynomial solution, but there are some heuristics and approximation algorithms.

Also, for relatively small integers, there is a Dynamic Programing solution that might be feasible, or if the input (number of elements) is relatively small - an exponential [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) solution can be used.