# How can I distribute databases across servers as evenly as possible while minimizing the movements required?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, greedy, bin-packing

The Problem:

- I'm attempting to create a program to redistribute ~1200 databases of various sizes across a finite number of servers to create as even a distribution as possible.  The databases are currently on those servers, but the distribution is uneven.
- I have looked at quite a few articles and stackoverflow/stackexchange posts but can't seem to find something that solves the whole issue.

Constraints:

- Databases are of drastically different sizes
- Need to Minimize the number of movements required to get to the even distribution
- the "weight" (how full) on each server needs to be as close as possible, we can say within 1% of each other.

What I have:

To create these even distributions I have the database identifier, the current server it exists on, the database size in Gbs, and the database size in a nominal data type that is relevant to the company as the operational database size. I have generated three clusters on the databases to split them into clusters of size based on the nominal data type that is relevant to the company as the operational database size and thus have them notated as "Small", "Medium", "Large".  I also have a Rank on each individual row which lists the databases from smallest to largest as a function of the two sizes available to me.

What I have looked into (with my understanding of why it wouldn't work):

Bin packing - minimizes the number of bins under the size constraint of the bin.  I need the algorithm to distribute evenly according to size among the bins while retaining knowledge of where they came from so we can get a count of movements required to get to the normalized distribution

Knapsack - Assume only one bin and pack it according to the size of the packages as well as their value to the person. I need more bins than that and I don't want maximum fullness in one bin before we move on to the next we need an even distribution.

K-Partition Problem - I don't see a way for this to count the number of movements.

Multiprocessor Scheduling - We have no time dimension and I don't see a way to see where the job is moving from so we can get the number of movements required to get to the end distribution.

What I need:

Direction on an algorithm (or an r package) that could help me solve this issue.

I have looked at:

- [Bin Packing: Set amount on bins, want to minimize the max bin weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825465/bin-packing-set-amount-on-bins-want-to-minimize-the-max-bin-weight)
- [What is the proper problem name / algorithm for this problem description in computer science theory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414982/what-is-the-proper-problem-name-algorithm-for-this-problem-description-in-comp)
- [The greedy algorithm and implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695202/the-greedy-algorithm-and-implementation)
- [Filling bins with an equal size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338915/filling-bins-with-an-equal-size)
- [Spread objects evenly over multiple collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588669/spread-objects-evenly-over-multiple-collections)

*Any direction would be very appreciated and if you have a link to further documentation as a reference to what you are discussing that would be lovely.*

Comment: How about you just *use a distributed database*? Cassandra seems to be popular nowadays

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the rationale for evenly distributing the data by size, instead of by access load?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated the question so it is more clear. Using Cassandra isn't really a solution for the issue at hand.

Comment: Size in terms of disk space is very rarely a useful indication of a database's resource consumption...

Comment: @cricket_007 Also we use SQL Server and it looks like Cassandra is NoSql.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I don't have a horse in that race. I was told the variables of interest and what they want the distribution based on.  If it is crazy bad I can bring it up to the project submitter but it isn't really my call.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Based on a response I received from a DBA the size (size in terms of disk space) is useful to us to determine their usage.  The bigger the database in terms of disk space the more they are used.